# Saving a PNG from Java program on OSX

Tags: java, macos, png

My program lets the user create and save a 'layout' file (a simple txt file which contains rectangle coords) and then also save a PNG graphic of that layout.

On linux, Windows and most Macs, there are no issues at all.
However I'm getting a few reports from mac users who say that the png image will not save. (Unfortunately no info regarding what osx version they are running yet.)

Save PNG file sample code :

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
final int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String directory = fc.getSelectedFile().toString();

    //here I create a buffered image of the layout, bi

    //set the image file name to be the selected directory plus the rect label
    String str = directory + "/" + s.getLabel();

        try {
            String path = new File(str + a + ".PNG").getAbsolutePath();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File(path));
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

I did have an issue earlier with read/write permissions (java can't write to system directories without being granted admin access.) but I don't think it is related. In these particular cases, I know that they are able to write to this folder as they can save their layout files there.

Comment: The `ie.printStackTrace()` is a problem.  If there is an error there, you'll never see it (only your user).  Use proper logging, and keep an in-memory buffer ([MemoryHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html))  When you get an error, sent a report to yourself, including a dump of the memory buffer.  Otherwise you'll never have any clue what is happening.

Comment: cheers might have to try this. I was hoping there'd be a known issue  with imageIO or something like that. cheers

Comment: ioexception doesn't seem to catch all failures with imageio, the best I can do is get the return value of ImageIO.write() and see if it was a success or failure, but still none the wiser as to knowing the underlying reason.